# What does this "if" statement mean?

Tags: python, if-statement

In an example Hadoop reduce program, such an "if" statement exists. I am wondering what it means when
the same variable "a" is used twice in the "if" statement, as follows

```
if a and a == b:
    print "It is working!"
```

Comment: It means you're checking to make sure `a` exists/isn't `False` and `b` is equal to `a`.

Comment: Basically if `a` exists or isn't false - and `a` is equal to `b` then print that statement

Answer (score 6):

It will test for equality (`a == b`) only if `a` is truthy.

It can be rewritten as

```
if a:
    if a == b:
        print("It is working!")
```

Note the operator precedence: it's ***not*** equal to `if (a and a) == b`.

Comment: This answer went from good to great with the comment about precedence.

Answer (score 4):

There's no real magic here.

And `and` expression is truthy iff both sides are truthy.

`a` is truthy iff it's not `False`, `None`, a numeric 0, or an empty collection.

`a == b` is truthy iff `a` and `b` are equal (in some sense appropriate to their type).

So, for example, if `a` and `b` can be either a list or `None`, this will be true if `a` is a non-empty list and `b` is a non-empty list with the same values.