# What does this if .. and not statement mean?

Tags: python, python-2.7

What does the following code mean:

```
if next == "taunt bear" and not bear_moved
```

bear_moved is filled with a value of false.

I've read this post: [What does this "if" statement mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25629857/what-does-this-if-statement-mean)
It explains that and 'and' operator tests for truth on both sides. If so, then does this code say, if next is equal to "taunt bear" and bear_moved is not true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's checking to see if `next` is equal to `"taunt bear"` and checking if `bear_moved` is falsey (a falsey value means it evaluates to false, truthy means it will evaluate to true). So as long as `next` is equal to `"taunt bear"` and `bear_moved` if not truthy, the if statement will succeed.

Answer (score 1):

It is using the Boolean operator "and" so both expressions have to be true in order for the if statement to execute

So if next has to equal "taunt bear" and also next has to equal not bear moved.

Not bear moved is just the opposite of bear moved or you can say not bear moved means False whereas bear moved is True.

It may help to look up Truth Tables in python.